# Eclipse RCP project Getting Exception "org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles"

Tags: windows, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have create an application Runner in eclipse RCP project. In my Runner application 
I am using Tree and in this tree I have a five treecolumn. Also create two treeItem one is parent and other child, put their values in treecolumn by programatically from database. In this table I have implemented multi selection combo and CCombo to get the multiple value.  If I pass almost 1000 of data in this table so I am getting  this
Exception:

org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles

If I debug this code I am getting this exception in CCombo or multicombo implementation.

I have two table Remote and Localhost both table getting data at the time of execution. Please find the below Code of my table  implementation. help me how to handle this exception.

```java
private void createTestSuiteTable( final Tree table) 
    {      

    /*Dispose all elements*/
      int[] selection = new int[] { 0 };
    TreeItem items[] = table.getItems();
    for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++)
    {
        items[i].dispose();
    }
//       remoteTable.removeAll();
    /*Get all remote computer IPs*/
    UserConfigurationGSON userGson = ConfigurationAPIHandler.getInstance().getSpecificConfiguration(Utilities.AUTOMATICS_USERNAME);
    String remoteComputerIPs[] =null;
    if(userGson.remoteMachines.size()>0)
    {
        remoteComputerIPs = new String[userGson.remoteMachines.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<userGson.remoteMachines.size();i++)
        {
            remoteComputerIPs[i] = userGson.remoteMachines.get(i).ip;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        remoteComputerIPs = new String[1];
        remoteComputerIPs[0] = "NONE";
    }
    /*Arraylist for Execution Type*/
    ArrayList<String> exeTypes = new ArrayList<String>(){{
                                        add("ANDROID_NATIVE");add("ANDROID_WEB");
                                        add("WINDOWS_WEB");add("WINDOWS_NONWEB");

                                    }};
    /*Arraylist for Execution Platform*/
    ArrayList<String> exePlatform = new ArrayList<String>(){{
                                        add("FireFox");add("IE");
                                        add("Chrome");add("Safari");
                                        }};

    TSGson tsGsons[] = TestSuiteAPIHandler.getInstance().getAllTestSuites();
    boolean checked=false;
    for (TSGson tsGson : tsGsons) 
    {
        parentTestSuite = new TreeItem(table, SWT.NONE|SWT.MULTI);
        parentTestSuite.setText(new String[] { "" +tsGson.tsName, "", "","","","" });
        parentTestSuite.setData("EltType","TESTSUITE");

        if(tsGson.tsTCLink==null)
                continue;

        if(table.equals(remoteTable))
        {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//              System.err.println("createTestSuiteTableRemote Strat Time"+startTime);
            for(TSTCGson tsTCGson : tsGson.tsTCLink) 
            {
                final TreeItem trtmTestcases = new TreeItem(parentTestSuite, SWT.NONE|SWT.MULTI);
                trtmTestcases.setText(new String[] {
                        tsTCGson.tcName, 
                        tsTCGson.tcParams.get(0)!=null ? tsTCGson.tcParams.get(0).tcparamValue:"",
                        tsTCGson.tcParams.get(1)!=null ? tsTCGson.tcParams.get(1).tcparamValue:"",
                        tsTCGson.tcParams.get(2)!=null ? tsTCGson.tcParams.get(2).tcparamValue:"",
                        tsTCGson.tcParams.get(3)!=null ? tsTCGson.tcParams.get(3).tcparamValue:"", 
                        tsTCGson.tcParams.get(4)!=null ? tsTCGson.tcParams.get(4).tcparamValue:"" });
                trtmTestcases.setData("EltType","TESTCASE");

                table.setSelection(parentTestSuite);
                if(checked)
                {
                      trtmTestcases.setChecked(checked);
                }

                final CCombo comboForRunOn = new CCombo(remoteTable, SWT.READ_ONLY| SWT.CHECK);
                comboForRunOn.setItems(remoteComputerIPs);

                /*Exe Type - WINDOWS, ANDROID*/

                final CCombo comboForExeType = new CCombo(remoteTable, SWT.READ_ONLY);
                comboForExeType.setItems(exeTypes.toArray(new String[exeTypes.size()]));
                comboForExeType.select(exeTypes.indexOf(tsTCGson.tcParams.get(1).tcparamValue));
                /*Exe Type - Firefox, IE, Chrome*/
                exePlatform.indexOf(tsTCGson.tcParams.get(1).tcparamValue);
                final MultiSelectionCombo comboForExePlatform = new MultiSelectionCombo(remoteTable,trtmTestcases,exePlatform.toArray(new String[exePlatform.size()]),selection, SWT.READ_ONLY| SWT.CHECK);

                TreeEditor editorForRunOn = new TreeEditor(remoteTable);
                TreeEditor editorForExeType = new TreeEditor(remoteTable);
                TreeEditor editorForExePlatform = new TreeEditor(remoteTable);
                editorForRunOn.setEditor(comboForRunOn, trtmTestcases, 3);
                editorForExeType.setEditor(comboForExeType, trtmTestcases, 2);
                comboForExeType.setText(tsTCGson.tcParams.get(1).tcparamValue);
                editorForExePlatform.setEditor(comboForExePlatform, trtmTestcases, 1);
                comboForExePlatform.setValueofDisplay(tsTCGson.tcParams.get(0).tcparamValue);

                editorForRunOn.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
                editorForRunOn.grabHorizontal = true;
                editorForExeType.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT; 
                editorForExeType.grabHorizontal = true;
                editorForExePlatform.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT; 
                editorForExePlatform.grabHorizontal = true;

                // Optional, but allows you to get the current value by calling
                // item.getText() instead of going through the TreeEditor and
                // calling ((CCombo) editor.getEditor()).getText()

                comboForRunOn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) 
                    {
                      trtmTestcases.setText(3, comboForRunOn.getText()); 
                    }
                });
                comboForExeType.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) 
                    {
                      trtmTestcases.setText(2, comboForExeType.getText());
                    }
                });

                long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

//                  System.err.println("Estimated time for reomte table"+estimatedTime);

            }
        }
```

Comment: You can't contact individual users like that (or any other way unless they have commented on the question). On Windows there is a limit of, I think, 10,000 handles. Most SWT controls use at least one handle, so you have probably simply got too many controls. You will have to come up with a simpler UI.

Comment: thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449

Comment: Putting links like that in a comment does not do anything. You can use somthing like @Biswabir but only to contact someone who has already commented.